# Unable to access KIbana in port 5601

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm trying to access kibana 5.2.0 installed in my Ubuntu 14 EC 2 machine.

When I try in my localhost to test it with:

```
curl 'http://IPNumber:5601'
```

I get:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 'IPnumber' port 5601: Connection refused
```

But when I try inside my EC2 instance:

curl 'localhost:5601'

I get:

```
<script>var hashRoute = '/app/kibana';
var defaultRoute = '/app/kibana';

var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash.length) {
  window.location = hashRoute + hash;
} else {
  window.location = defaultRoute;
```

My EC2 I have a security rule for Outbound traffic with the following options:

Type:Custom TCP Rule
Protocol:TCP
Port Range:5601
Destination: mypublicip connection

What's wrong with this setup?
In my localhost this works, but it doesn't in ec2.

Comment: Could you give the o/p of command `netstat -ntpl | grep 5601` in your ubuntu ec2 instance.